# How to apply Rules of inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know the definition for `Rules of inference`

> "A rule of inference is a general pattern that allows us to draw some
>   new conclusion from a set of given statements. If we know P then we
>   can conclude Q."

But, not sure how can i prove ¬ C ⇒ ¬ (B ∧ (B ⇒ C)) by Rules of inference?.

Comment: If we have B and B implies C then we have 1) B implies C and 2) B.  Therefore we must have C.  So if we know C is false.  Then (B and B implies C) must also be false (otherwise C would be true).  So not C implies not B and B implies C.

Comment: If we have B and B implies C then we have 1) B implies C and 2) B. Why and How 2) B? please explain as i didn't get this point.

Comment: If you have "X and Y" then you have 1) X and 2) Y.  How can you not?  so if you have "B and (B =>C)", then you have 1) "B" and 2) "B => C". and by modus ponens you therefore have 3) C.